# JMX RMI - Memory Leak - ArrayNotificationBuffer getting bigger over time

Tags: java, memory-leaks, rmi, jmx

i'm writing an application that should run many hours (10-100) which i'm monitoring using JMX.

However, after some time, i discover two things:

- `com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayNotificationBuffer#1` gets bigger: after 20 hours, it's about 10MB - when i started it, it was smaller than 1 MB
- More threads like `RMI TCP Accept-0` (or any other number) and `RMI-TCP-Connection(44)-[IP]` are instanciated over time.

I'm thinking, that it has something to do with different connections to the application, but currently i'm just connected once, but some connections still seem to be open.

How can that be? How can i fix this?

Comment: I wouldn't use RMI + JMX to monitor the application over an extended period of time. It can produce quite a bit of garbage. I would use a simple log file and/or socket which publishes just the information you need.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? i want memory and CPU usage statistics. i don't see why i should completely write it by myself

Comment: You don't need to re-invent the wheel unless its always going flat on you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was poking around in the source code comments for [ArrayNotificationBuffer](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/jmx/remote/internal/ArrayNotificationBuffer.java.html) and it has a decent amount of JMX trace logging, so you might want to [enable JMX tracing](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/tracing_jmx_what_s_going) to get a better idea of what's going on.

You may find that [this known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6957378) is affecting you. The bug report indicates the issue is observed on long lasting connections. There's a couple of work-arounds mentioned, although a simpler one is not, if practical to you, which is to periodically disconnect and reconnect. The good news is that there appears to be a [patch](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/jdk/rev/5de001f5f8b4) for this in Java7, although I'm not sure if it has reached a released build yet.

I would also make sure that if you are registering JMX notification listeners, that they are continually and promptly handling notifications. Failure to do so might also be causing this symptom.